# Filtering Custom Options Collection

Tags: collection-filtering, magento-1.4

Given a collection obtained by (this is Magento 1.4):

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')
    ->getProductOptionCollection($_product);
```

This returns the collection of options associated with a single product. I would like to filter this down to only give me options that have a `price_type` of `percent`, so naturally, I try:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')
    ->getProductOptionCollection($_product)
    ->addFieldToFilter('price_type', array('eq' => 'percent'));
```

This still returns the entire option collection, as if the filter did nothing at all. Is this an old issue with v.1.4?

Comment: Did you try changing `price_type` to `default_option_price.price_type`?

Comment: Indeed I have. For now, I have resorted to a couple `foreach` loops that gets the values from each option and just pushes those with `['price_type'] == 'percent'` to a new array. This is an old site that will be gone soon and I'm not able to spend much time on it and I fear that some of the rewritten models (including options, products, values, etc) are what is giving me fits.

Answer (score 1):

Testing the query product by your code in version 1.7.* i got the following error in MySql Workbench  "Error Code: 1052. Column 'price_type' in where clause is ambiguous"

Try

```
 $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1);
 $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')
               ->getProductOptionCollection($_product)
               ->addFieldToFilter('default_option_price.price_type', array('eq' => 'percent'));
```

Try debugging using

```
echo $collection->getSelect();
```

See

v1.7

> /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Option/Collection.php

v1.4

> /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Option/Collection.php